# Android Service hanging after returning to the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I find this issue very interesting, some might not. Let's hope I get a solid answer.

I have a Fragment, which binds a service in `onResume()` to automatically refresh the data every 60 seconds while the user is present. My `bind()` method here...

```
public void bind() {
    if(connected || MainActivity.sRefresherBinding) return;
    MainActivity.sRefresherBinding = true;
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "binding...");
    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Service Connected!");
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("We're almost there!");
    Intent bindingIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Refresh.class);
    getActivity().bindService(bindingIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    getActivity().startService(bindingIntent);
}
```

Corresponding `unbind()` method here called in `onStop()`...

```
public void unbind() {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "unbinding");
        if (connected) {
            mRefreshService.terminate();
            getActivity().unbindService(mConnection);
            getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(), Refresh.class));
            connected = false;
        }
    }
```

`onServiceConnected()` here...

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        if(binder != null) binder = null;
        binder = (Refresh.LocalBinder) service;
        if(mRefreshService != null) mRefreshService.terminate();
        mRefreshService = binder.getService();
        connected = true;
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Refreshing your data...");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("We are almost there!");
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Service Connected");
    }
```

My `onStartCommand()` on Refresh extends Service

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    start(new UpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(ArrayList<Quote.SingleQuote> newData) {
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
            broadcastIntent.setAction(Utility.BROADCAST);
            broadcastIntent.putExtra(Utility.QUOTE_INTENT, newData);
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }
    });

    if (mHandler == null) {
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.post(mRunnable);
    }

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

The runnable...

```
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        refreshMain();
        if (mHandler != null)
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, MIN_UPDATE_TIME);
    }
};
```

refreshMain is too large, I'll just post the snippet where the result is sent back to the listener...

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Quote>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<Quote> response) {
                try {                        
                    List<Quote.SingleQuote> asList = response.body().query.results.getQuote();
                    mQuotes = new ArrayList<>(asList);
                    mListener.onUpdate(mQuotes);
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Refreshed");

                }
```

And finally my Broadcast Receiver...

```
public static class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        if(MainFragmentService.getInstance().mProgressDialog != null) MainFragmentService.getInstance().mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        if(MainFragmentService.getInstance() != null) {
            MainFragmentService.getInstance().mQuotes = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Utility.QUOTE_INTENT);
            MainFragmentService.getInstance().mAdapter.swapList(MainFragmentService.getInstance().mQuotes);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Package received");
            MainActivity.sRefresherBinding = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the tricky part.
All of this code works beatifully on my nexus 5, but when I run it on my Nexus 7, go into another Activity and come back, the service hangs. The data is fetched, broadcasted, picked up, BUT the dialog doesn't get dismissed and the data is not displayed in the recycler view.

A look at the logcat on my Nexus 5:

```
V/MainFragmentService: onPause
V/MainFragmentService: unbinding
V/MainFragmentService: onStop
V/MainFragmentService: onResume
V/MainFragmentService: binding...
V/Refresh: RefreshMain called
V/MainFragmentService: Service Connected
V/Refresh: Refreshed
V/MainFragmentService: Package received
```

Now a look at the logcat on my Nexus 7:

```
V/MainFragmentService: onPause
V/MainFragmentService: unbinding
V/MainFragmentService: onStop
V/MainFragmentService: onResume
V/MainFragmentService: binding...
V/MainFragmentService: onResume
V/Refresh: RefreshMain called
V/MainFragmentService: Service Connected
V/Refresh: Refreshed
V/MainFragmentService: Package received
V/Refresh: Waiting
V/Refresh: Waiting
V/Refresh: RefreshMain called
V/Refresh: Refreshed
V/MainFragmentService: Package received
```

In case you have doubts about this code working at all, the app is right here, go [nuts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=us.hnry.fancy). If you read this through, thanks for your time!

Comment: Well I read through to the end .. Unfortunately not a clue why its not refreshing! What happens on the Nexus 7 when the dialog doesn't dismiss, but you rotate the tablet - does it sort itself out when rotated?

Comment: @MarkKeen I added the line in the manifest that prevents the activity from being destroyed on configuration changes because, again on the Nexus 7, it was creating multiple threads with the same service. Multiple calls to the server, both of them broadcasting, and neither one of them was populating the recycler view. I've yet to try removing that line from the manifest, since adding the controls in bind() and on service connected(). I'll try as soon as I get back on my computer.

Comment: @MarkKeen I can confirm that the controls effectively prevent the service from being instantiated multiple times. Can't say the same about the fragment. [logcat](http://imgur.com/hk3V9cG) of what happens when I rotate the device a few times. That is on my phone, where the information does get updated and displayed regardless of the mess. I'll look into this. In any case, issue on the Nexus 7 persists after a few hours of digging around on the internet.

Comment: How do you stop your `Runnable`? I don't understand how it stops running on your Nexus 5 when you have `if (mHandler != null) mHandler.postDelayed(this, MIN_UPDATE_TIME);` running every `MIN_UPDATE_TIME`.

Comment: @RicardoLage `unbind()` called in the Fragment's `onStop()`. The problem is not on the Nexus 5, it's on the Nexus 7. I've actually confirmed from feedback of people using different devices (Motorola, Samsung, LG) and different versions of Android, and the app works as it's programmed to do. I haven't found another device where I can replicate the issue.

Comment: @this I understood that the problem is not on the Nexus 5, but I'm not really understanding the setup you have. `unbind()` is called when you leave the fragment. When you return to it, you call `bind()` again and your `Runnable()` will run non-stop, no?

Comment: @RicardoLage Follow [github link](https://github.com/JerryZaz/Fancy/blob/refresh_service/app%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fus%2Fhnry%2Ffancy%2Fservices%2FRefresh.java) for the full code. I'll be merging as I was able to track down the issue so the link might be broken when you check back in. [Project](https://github.com/JerryZaz/Fancy) in case the other link is broken. Comments and suggestions are most welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue tracked down to Developer Options > Apps > Don't keep activities enabled on the Nexus 7, disabled on the Nexus 5 (and others).

Meaning that the real issue was on the Activity itself, which was being destroyed when navigating out of it. When navigating back, a new Fragment was being created on top of the existing one because I wasn't checking the `savedInstanceState`. The mess mentioned in the comments above is now fixed as well, no need to prevent the activity destruction on configuration changes through the Manifest anymore.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_main_list_container,
new MainFragmentService(), FRAGMENT_TAG_MAIN_LIST).commit();
```

Now is...

```
MainFragmentService mainFragment;
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            mainFragment = new MainFragmentService();
            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content_main_list_container,
                            mainFragment, FRAGMENT_TAG_MAIN_LIST)
                    .commit();
        }
```